# JavaFX - BorderPane, ensuring that Right Pane gets always a minimum width

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I have the following JavaFX FXML structure:

```xml
<BorderPane fx:id="mainWindow" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@mainwindow.css"/>
    </stylesheets>

    <top>
        <fx:include fx:id="buttonPanel" source="/com/example/app/chart/buttons/buttonPanel.fxml" />
    </top>
    <center>
        <BorderPane fx:id="chartContainer">
            <center>
                <fx:include fx:id="chartPanel" source="/com/example/app/chart/chartpanel/chartPanel.fxml" />
            </center>
            <right>
                <fx:include fx:id="rightAxisPanel" source="/com/example/app/chart/rightaxis/rightAxisPanel.fxml" />
            </right>
        </BorderPane>
    </center>

</BorderPane>
```

Being `chartPanel` and `rightAxisPanel`:

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="chartPanel" styleClass="chartPanelClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@chartpanel.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

and

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="rightAxisPanel" prefWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" styleClass="rightAxisPanelClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@rightaxispanel.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

This generates the following figure:

[image: image1]

So far, so good.

But if I reduce the size of the window, the right panel is the one that is truncated -see how yellow area which corrsponds to the rigthAxisPanel is truncated-.

**How can I do to get the central panel the one being truncated?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal width of the center `AnchorPane` prevents it from shrinking. Set the value to 0 to make sure it's allowed to shrink.

Furthermore you should apply a `clip` to the `AnchorPane` to avoid it's content from showing up to the right of it's right bound. This could happen, if you use (half) transparent background on the right, change the `viewOrder` or if you put a right node in the outer `BorderPane`.

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="chartPanel" styleClass="chartPanelClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" minWidth="0">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@chartpanel.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <clip>
        <Rectangle width="${chartPanel.width}" height="${chartPanel.height}"/>
    </clip>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: it works, thanks for the extra tip on the clipping. I also needed that.